# Porque o background-image url procura a imagem dentro da pasta Content?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu tenho um CSS assim:

```css
#hero {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("~/img/bg-img.jpg");
  background-position: top center;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Quando eu rodo, a imagem não aparece, quando eu mando inspecionar elemento ele procura a imagem dentro desse link, `http://localhost:58966/Content/~/img/bg-img.jpg`

Porque ele procura dentro da pasta Content, ele deveria procurar em `"http://localhost:58966/img/bg-img.jpg"`

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todos os caminhos que começam com / são absolutos, todos os caminhos que começam sem / são relativos.

Ele está procurando na pasta Content porque você especificou um caminho relativo (`~/img/bg-img.jpg`). Ou seja, como o seu arquivo CSS está na pasta Content, ele irá colocar o seu caminho no final da URL do arquivo em CSS: `http://localhost:58966/Content/` + `~/img/bg-img.jpg`.

Como você quer que o caminho seja http://localhost:58966/img/bg-img.jpg, é possível fazer isso de pelo menos duas formas:

- Caminho absoluto: `background-image: url("/img/bg-img.jpg");`
- Caminho relativo: `background-image: url("../img/bg-img.jpg");`

Answer (score 0):

Para o seu caso, isto resolve:

```
#hero {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("/Content/img/bg-img.jpg");
  background-position: top center;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

O CSS não interpreta `~`.